# how can we charge bulk cards on stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I am working on crowd funding php script using stripe for storing cards from customers.
I am stuck at point of charging cards of all backers if threshold is met . Using a loop in php script gets stopped after Stripe's api maximum execution time is reached at 120 seconds.

```
<?php 
include('system/stripelib/lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey(API);
//getting saved stripe Customer_id 
$result= $this->db->query("select cus_id,amount from pledge where 1");
if($result->num_rows)
{                  
    foreach($result->rows as $cus)
    {

         Stripe_Charge::create(array(
          "amount" => $cus['amount']
          "currency" => "usd",
          "customer" => $cus['cus_id'],
          "description" => "Charge for campaign"
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's probably PHP's execution limit, not Stripe's.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. You just need to wrap your `Stripe_Charge::create` calls in a `try`/`catch` (and the [associated error handling](http://www.larryullman.com/2013/01/30/handling-stripe-errors/)) so that network errors, rate limiting or even declines don't break the whole thing.

Comment: I got error from stripe api , however I think wrapping in try catch and using loop would do it ..